# How to write a LINQ join for two classes in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, linq, ef-code-first

I am having trouble accessing a property from a joined table, using EF Code First.  Here is my query in my home controller:

```
var pcs = from h in db.Hardwares
    join hwt in db.HardwareTypes 
    on h.HardwareTypeId equals hwt.Id
    where h.HardwareType.HType == "PC"
    select new { Hardware = h, HardwareType = hwt };   

ViewBag.Pcs = pcs.ToList();
```

Here is my HardwareTypes class:

```
public class HardwareType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        //[Required]
        //[StringLength(128)]
        public string HType { get; set; }

    }
```

Here is my Hardware class:

```
public class Hardware
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int HardwareTypeId { get; set;}
        public virtual HardwareType HardwareType { get; set; } 

    }
```

How do I change my LINQ query so `HType` is in my `ViewBag`?  The database seems to be generating correctly, it's just I can't seem to access `HType`.  I get an error `'object' does not contain a definition for 'HType'`

Comment: Are you asking to change the query itself to say `where h.HardwareType.HType == ViewBag.HType`?

Comment: I just want to have HType in my ViewBag

Comment: I'm just trying to better what you're trying to do. It's slightly confusing. Are you trying to query off of what's in the ViewBag, or are you trying to populate the ViewBag with the result of the query?

Comment: I want to populate the ViewBag with the data from the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, time for a full reset. Based on the chat, I want you to try the following:

1) Keep your original LINQ query, but don't make it an anonymous type. Create another object type that will have a Hardware and a HardwareType property in it. This will make Pcs (as well as ViewBag.Pcs) a List of that particular type.

2) Put the following foreach loop in your View code:

```
foreach (var item in ViewBag.Pcs as List<YourTypeName>)
{
   var htype = item.HardwareType.HType;
}
```

And if you don't want to do some lazy loading each time through the loop, you can do the following in the controller to just load up the entities right away:

```
var hardwareTypes = pcs.Select(p => p.HardwareType).ToList();
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: This will cause a lazy evaluation of HardwareType in each iteration oo the loop. You should use an Include to load the HardwareType with the Hardware list in a single query.

Comment: I normalized my tables so that HardwareTypes are in a separate table.  I need the join.

Comment: I understand that. But you clearly have a 1:1 relationship based on the Hardware class having a HardwareType property.

Comment: @sehummel. I think you need to read a little more into entity framework. Based on your class definitions, the join is not necessary because EF already knows the FK contrainst exists and will do the hard work for you.

Comment: Yeah, I'm definitely an EF newbie.  I'm trying.

Comment: @IronMan84 - I don't think it's a one-to-one. Presumably it's a one-to-many. (Assumption) There can be many hardwares of a given type. That said, it's irrelevant.

Comment: It is one-to-many.  One hardware can have many hardware types.

Comment: Ah, that would explain that.

Comment: I don't think so. Let me edit it. Unless it does work (based on accepting my answer)?

Comment: Actually, it would work depending on what you're trying to do. If you're trying to make a grid on the page with each record representing a Hardware record, and having the HType as a column in the grid it would work fine.

Comment: I get this error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Ok, let's try this anew. What are you trying to show in your View?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21788/discussion-between-sehummel-and-ironman84)

Comment: I created a ViewModel with the properties in it and used my original LINQ query.  That worked.  Thanks, @IronMan84!